# Having trouble with expected values

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

What would be the expected value of a random variable with distribution $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k^2-k}$? I'm basically stuck. $k \in [2, \infty) \cap \mathbb N$.

Comment: What are the values? $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It should be $k\in[2,\infty)\cap\mathbb{N}$ I think because otherwise the integral does not sum up to 1.

Comment: @ShuXiaoLi: I think you are right and updated problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, let's be a little more careful with our wording. Assuming $X$ is a random variable with probability mass function
$$
p(k) = \frac{1}{k^2-k} = \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}
$$
for $k \geq 2$, we would like to calculate $E[X]$.

First note that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(k)$ is nonnegative a telescoping series which sums to $1$, so it indeed defines a valid probability measure.

Then we calculate
$$
E[X] = \sum_{k=2}^\infty k p(k) =  \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k-1} = \infty.
$$

Comment: So the fact that it goes off to infinity does not necessarily mean that I calculated the distribution incorrectly?

Comment: No, it does not mean that you did anything wrong. Some random variables have infinite expectation (including this one). One should be careful though, if the random variable is allowed to take negative values then $E[X]$ might not be well defined. If $X \geq 0$ (like this case) you need not worry though.

Comment: How does one arrive at the fact that this summation goes off to infinity? From ∑k=2->∞ 1/k−1 to this: ∞.

Comment: This is the harmonic series which is well known to diverge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics) There are many proofs that can be found on wikipedia for this result.

Answer (score 4):

If $p_k = \dfrac{1}{k^2 - k}$, then:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{1}{k^2 - k} = \sum_{k \ge 2} \left( \frac{1}{k - 1} - \frac{1}{k} \right) = 1
$$
OK, so we want:
$$
\mathbb{E}(k) = \sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{k}{k^2 - k} = \sum_{k \ge 2} \frac{1}{k - 1} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}
$$
This sum doesn't exist (the harmonic series diverges).

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k^2-k}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k-1}=\infty$$
Does not converge.

Comment: That's what I thought. If this is the case, does that most likely mean that I am approaching the problem incorrectly?

Comment: @John There are many distributions that do not have a "mean". So ending up with divergent mean does not mean incorrect.

Comment: @John, not necessarily. The result is OK, the probabilities sum up to 1 as they should.